# rosbag record error

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following error when trying to record a bag file about image transport. I thought if the system could send a msg using ros then it should be able to record it and play ?

```
[ INFO] [1511280765.822614770, 1341848150.120971094]: Subscribing to /flame/manager/bond
[ INFO] [1511280765.824873532, 1341848150.120971094]: Subscribing to /flame/idepth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1511280765.827001685, 1341848150.120971094]: Subscribing to /flame/depth_registered/image_rect
[ INFO] [1511280765.829221068, 1341848150.120971094]: Subscribing to /flame/debug/wireframe/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1511280765.831393080, 1341848150.125999109]: Subscribing to /flame/idepth_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1511280765.833637242, 1341848150.125999109]: Subscribing to /flame/debug/wireframe/theora
[ INFO] [1511280765.836285744, 1341848150.125999109]: Subscribing to /flame/idepth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
[ INFO] [1511280765.838769213, 1341848150.125999109]: Subscribing to /flame/depth_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ERROR] [1511280765.870219731, 1341848150.146124729]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1341848149.738777917 but the earliest data is at time 1341848149.770782628, when looking up transform from frame [openni_rgb_optical_frame] to frame [world]
[ERROR] [1511280767.902958519, 1341848151.159780581]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires 

single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: bgr8).

[ERROR] [1511280767.885934564, 1341848151.149720892]: Compressed Image Transport - JPEG compression requires 8/16-bit color format (input format is: 32FC1)
[ERROR] [1511280767.887200374, 1341848151.149720892]: cv_bridge exception: '[32FC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is. The conversion does not make sense'
[ERROR] [1511280767.897593405, 1341848151.159780581]: Compressed Image Transport - JPEG compression requires 8/16-bit color format (input format is: 32FC1)
[ERROR] [1511280767.898571188, 1341848151.159780581]: cv_bridge exception: '[32FC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is. The conversion does not make sense'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276415/rosbag-record-error/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-21**:
These look like log messages from several different nodes. Are you running rosbag record from a launch file?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-11-21**:
yes...from a launch file...If i take out the rosbag record then I do not get the transport errors.I am running flame_ros.

```
 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="flame_bagger"  output="screen"  args=" -a -o flameBag"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect these errors are actually coming from your image publisher, probably because rosbag is trying to subscribe to a compressed topic that the publisher can't actually publish.

You should be able to confirm this by running your image publisher and rosbag in separate terminals.

Once you've confirmed that this is a problem, I suggest that you adjust the options to rosbag record to limit which topics are recorded; this will both prevent these errors and potentially reduce the size of your recorded bag file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-11-30**:
restricted recording as suggested.